# Вопрос о сущностях (POJO)

Tags: java

Вопрос из теории. Как правильнее создавать сущности (POJO): как объекты, отражающие строки БД или как объекты, выводимые в UI. Смотрел в примерах, все делают по-разному.

Comment: Часто делают и то, и другое. А внутри приложения переливают поля туда-сюда.

Comment: @iksuy Т.е. создают отдельно POJO для строки БД, отдельно для UI и где-нибудь в Business Layer их коммутируют?

Comment: Да, именно так. В зависимости от количества слоев таких POJO может быть не два, а больше.

Comment: И лежать эти объекты, как я понимаю, должны в соответствующих слоях (сущности таблиц БД в DAO, сущности представления компонент окна в VM и т.д.)?

Comment: Оставлю тут [ссылку](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/examples.html) на случай, если вам захочется придумывать свой велосипед.

Comment: @enzo Не совсем то, но близко. Кроме маппинга полей сущностей в моем случае нужно еще производить кое-какую обработку значений. Так что, таки да, мне проще придумать свой велосипед.

Answer (score 1):

Как объекты отражающие название столбцов в БД

Comment: Ну вот, мнения разделились.